# Spring JPA/Hibernate @ManyToOne relationship always inserting child row

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm attempting to use Spring JPA/Hibernate to maintain a Parent table with a child table related based on an Id. If I attempt to insert the same object twice, the Parent table gets "updated" properly, but the child table is always inserted to even though the entry in the child table is already present.

```
CREATE TABLE `parent_table` (
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ex_column_1` int(11) NOT NULL, // there is a unique constraint on this field - I just didn't include it
  `ex_column_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `child_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Child Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `child_table` (
  `child_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `child_col_1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`child_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

POJOs:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_table")
public final class Parent {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private long id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ex_column_1")
    private int exampleField;

    @Column(name = "ex_column_2")
    private int exampleField2;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", unique = true)
    private Child c;

    public Parent(/*params*/) {}

    // getters ...

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "child_table")
    public static final class Child {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "child_id")
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "child_col_1")
        private exampleChildField;

        public Child(/*params*/) {}

        // getters ...
    }
}
```

Actual example of how POJO's are constructed and saved:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/parents")
public final class ParentController {
    private final ParentRepository parentRepository;

    @Inject
    public ParentController(final ParentRepository parentRepository) {
        parentRepository = parentRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void updateParents(@RequestBody Parent[] parents) {

        // ignore input for now, test by constructing object

        Parent.Child c = new Parent.Child(0L, "test 1");
        Parent p = new Parent(0L, "unique_column_1", "column_2", c);
        Set<Parent> pSet = new HashSet<>();
        pSet.add(p);

       parentRepository.save(pSet);
    }
}
```

Repository Layer:

```
public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, Long>, ParentRepositoryCustom {}

public interface ParentRepositoryCustom {
    void save(Set<Parent> parents);    
}

@Repository
final class ParentRepositoryImpl implements ParentRepositoryCustom {
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    public EmployerRepositoryImpl(final EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Set<Parent> parents) {
        parents.forEach(parent -> {
            Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
            session.saveOrUpdate(parent);
        });
    }
}
```

If the entry in either table doesn't exist, it persists both entities just fine and links the proper Ids between tables. The issue occurs if the same parent and child object are inserted again. The UPDATE occurs on the Parent table, but an INSERT on the child:

```
Hibernate: insert into child_table (child_col_1) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into parent_table (ex_column_1, ex_column_2, child_id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

On second insert:

```
Hibernate: insert into child_table (child_col_1) values (?)
Hibernate: update parent_table set ex_column_2=?, child_id=? where ex_column_1=?
```

How do I get EntityManager to persist these correctly if the entry already exists?

Comment: You have a weird database. Is there only 1 child per parent, in which case it should be OneToOne not ManyToOne.

Comment: I've factored down the example to be a simple as possible, but in the real use case, there could be multiple parent table entries to an entry in the child table.

Comment: Post the code where you create the entities to be persisted.

Comment: Can you show some code that you use to insert and update the dB? Preferably a JUnit  test.

Comment: @AlanHay there really isn't much code to show for creating the entities. The objects get created using some fake data. I'll update my example to show how they are being constructed. I have a striking suspicion that because the child id is 0, Spring tries to query that table to find a row with ID 0 and cannot find it, thus performing the insert. The right question might be, how can I query the second table properly so it gets updated instead of inserted as a new row?

Comment: As advised you need to post through full code where you are creating and calling save.

Comment: You are creating and saving TWO instances. Both people offering help have asked for the FULL code where you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found issue. The client that is used to post new "parent" objects to the rest interface, by default, sets the primary key ids to 0. This works for the parent because ex_column_1 is an ID that's known at the time objects get created by some other mechanism.

On the other hand, the Child object only has a primary key as its Id and by setting it to zero, Spring attempts to find a related child row based on an id of zero, and always does an insert instead of an update if a child row already exists. Doing a simple check using the EntityManager.find() method on both objects then saving or merging fixed it.